# Install Composer on MAMP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, installation, composer-php, mamp

So here is the issue I'm getting:

I'm trying to install `Composer` and I'm using `MAMP` on Windows (it does exist since the beginning of January).

And like many users of `Composer` on Windows, I've got this error :

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl"
```

So I checked on the right `php.ini` page if it was unabled and it was!

I can't find any help since there are very few users of `MAMP` on Windows.

Thank you for your help or suggestions

Comment: Are you using the PHP.exe from MAMP? Or another one?

Comment: I'm using the php.exe located in \MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.3 but there is not php.ini in that folder (only php.ini-production or php.ini-development) @RaphaëlGonçalves

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Open php.ini located in your "`\MAMP\conf\`" folder or copy the php.ini into a `\MAMP\bin\php\php[your PHP version number]\`
2. Find "`extension=php_openssl.dll`"
3. `;extension=php_openssl.dll` - remove "`;`"
4. Restart your MAMP , extension should be loaded after that.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick ! Just had to copy paste the php.ini into the bin directory.

Comment: check answer by @ark for most recent method to install composer

Comment: @ark I get that Composer looks for it there, but doesn't that mean you now have to change both php.ini files every time you make a change?

Comment: For me, I *HAD* to copy the `php.ini` file to a `\bin\php...` folder.   Just fixing the `php.ini` in the `\conf` still caused the error

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem.

**The solution is quite easy:**
Ensure that `extension=php_openssl.dll` is uncommented (Remove `;`) **and copy** the php.ini file at **the same directory** where the php.exe is located, because Composer searches there for an php.ini File and not in the MAMP conf folder.

Comment: I also had to copy the php.ini file to the same directory where php.exe is located to successfully install Composer

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:** Go to following Folder

```
\MAMP\bin\php\php[your php version you are working on]
```

**Note:** to check **version** of php you are using go to **Mamp prefrences** and then click on **php** tab and there you can see Standard Version  the version you are using.

```
mine was \MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.8
```

**Step 2:** Inside that folder find file named as

```
 php.ini-production
```

**Step 3:** Open this file in **Notepad** to edit

**Step 4:** Search for by pressing **ctrl+F**

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

**Step 5:** **Remove** Semicolon(`;`) before it

**Step 6:** Restart **MAMP** and **voila** You are ready to install **Composer.**

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of an explanation to your answer? It might help OP or future users more.

Comment: I did explanation and improved formatting too. that was my first answer so. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

This method works as of version 3.2.2:

1. Open `php.ini` located in your `\MAMP\conf\` folder and copy the `php.ini` file into `\MAMP\bin\php\php[your PHP version number]\` (You can find the version number you are using in MAMP's preferences)
2. Find `extension=php_openssl.dll` remove `;` if it exists.
3. Open `php.ini-production` and `php.ini-developmen` that exist in the same folder that you copied the `php.ini` file into.
4. Find `extension=php_openssl.dll` remove `;` if it exists.
5. Restart your MAMP, and the extension should be loaded after that and you should be able to install Composer.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this issue, followed the suggested answers and couldn't get it working.

So to anyone else getting a bunch of errors, remember MAMP is still in Beta for windows and some issues will run deeper than is practical to fix.

> MAMP & MAMP PRO for Windows is available as a Beta version. It may still contain some. We do not recommend using MAMP & MAMP PRO Beta for Windows in a production environment.

In the end I had to switch to WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a bit of time too. In my Windows 10 MAMP installation the openssl extension was enabled by default in all php.ini files. I got it working by adding the desired PHP version to the Windows system PATH before installing Composer. MAMP PRO has a setting 'PHP in system' path on the 'PHP' tab of control panel.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with MAMP PRO on Windows 7, and I assume MAMP would be the same.

The tricky step is you have to copy the php.ini file to your php.exe location in order to install composer. (MAMP PRO leaves these in separate locations)

For example I am using php 5.6.0, you can use any version just make the appropriate changes.

STEPS:

1. Path for php.exe C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.0\php.exe
2. Path For php.ini C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\conf\php5.6.0.ini
3. Edit the php.ini from step 2 as necessary (uncomment openssl)
4. Copy the php5.6.0.ini from step 2 to the php.exe directory from step 1
5. Rename this copied php5.6.0.ini to just php.ini

Composer should then be able to install correctly.